# Why is there a Foursquare v2 API javascript authentication method?

Tags: ajax, api, foursquare

Browsing though the Foursquare API documentation, I noticed that when obtaining an access token with ajax there is no need for a secret key (for obvious reasons). But this makes me wonder what is even the point of having to register apps with foursquare in the first place if you can just fake being any app by using their client key. Why do they allow this?

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in the document you referred to

> Since each credential is tied to a particular URL

The point is Foursquare is looking at the URL of the requesting script for security. If there is no registration there is no URL to tie the credentials to.

Comment: As a side note after thinking about what I do when I write a public API, for security reasons I try using 4 credentials if possible, public key, private key, requesting server IP and requesting URL. This means any single query should have at least 3 of the credentials and if it doesn't have all required for that query correct the API will not parse the data being requested. This is my personal method but it is not always viable depending on the API being written and the nature of the platform/app. Just my extra 2 cents

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot that the redirect url is tied to the app. Well then on a second note, why have a private key, as it seems that only one or the other is necessary?

Comment: The public keys will generally go with user submitted queries, the private keys will be used for queries that are gathering information so the user can submit. An example would be if you need a user ID before content is submitted by the user, the user ID will be requested by the private key, when the user submits the information the public key will be used. The reason for this is to prevent forgery and SPAM-like submissions as the private key will never be accessible to the world, the public key may at times be visible in a form or JavaScript depending on what it is intended for.